# Multiple times of input in the same text field with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code i can only input ones. If ever there are any changes of any row of column `Term4`, the value of the `Ave` is blank. How to make it dynamic? I need help here because all my codes were only searched piece by piece until i came up with this script. I'm stuck here for days. Any help would be a blessing. This is my first input...

**Sample table, output 1**:

```
Subject | Term1 | Term2 | Term3 | Term4 |   Ave  
   Math      81      87      81      80    82.4 
Science      89      83      81      80    83.25
```

If i change the input in `term 4`, the `ave` column will be blank.

**Sample table output 2**:

```
Subject | Term1 | Term2 | Term3 | Term4 | Ave 
   Math      81      87      81      85     
Science      89      83      81      80   83.25
```

**HTML**:

```
<tr>                 
     <th colspan="3">Learning Areas</th>
     <th colspan="2">Term 1</th>
     <th colspan="2">Term 2</th>
     <th colspan="2">Term 3</th>
     <th colspan="2">Term 4</th>
     <th>Ave</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
          @foreach($card['AllGrade'] as $subject)
          {!! Form::hidden('grade_id[]',$subject['grade_id']) !!} 
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">{!! $subject->subject !!}</td>
      <td colspan="2">{!! $subject->term_1 !!}</td>
      <td colspan="2">{!! $subject->term_2 !!}</td>
      <td colspan="2">{!! $subject->term_3 !!}</td>
      <td colspan="2">{!! Form::text('term_4[]',$subject->term_4,['class'=>'form-control','name'=>'term_4','id'=>'term_4','value'=>'']) !!}</td>

    <td colspan="2" class="aver" name ="ave" id ="ave" value=""> total</td>

         </tr>
      @endforeach


//javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
$("tbody tr").each(function() {
    var total = 0;
    var ave = 0;
    var count = 1;


        $(this).children('td').not(':first').not(':last').each(function () {
        //"this" is the current element in the loop

        var number = ($(this).children('input').length == 0) ? $(this).html() : $(this).children('input').first().val();

        total += parseInt(number);
        ave = total/count;
        count++;
});


    if('.form-control'){
        $(this).on('keyup', 'td:eq( 4 ) input', function(){
             $('.form-control').on("input", function() {
                var dInput = this.value;
                total += parseInt(dInput);

                 ave = total/count-1; 

             });

           console.log(ave);
          $(this).parent().next().html(ave);

     });
    }   

      $(this).children('td').last().html(ave);
```

Comment: Sorry for the table,I cant edit.Note:Sample table output2: after Term4 with value 85, the Ave value is blank. Thats were i made my changes.The second time arround i'd made changes on the the input,nothings happened on the Ave column.

Comment: I was about to edit the post but there is no edit button after posting.This is supposed to be the view that i want.Thank you Sir.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, but I can tell you that `if('.form-control')` will always be true (because `if('any non-empty string')` is always true), and also adding event handlers from inside other event handlers (i.e., nested `.on()` calls) is generally not the right approach for most problems.

Comment: @nnnnnn- Sir ,please see my Sample table, output 1: and compare to Sample table output 2.The value of Term4 inline with the Math subject, inthe first table the value is 80 with the ave of 82.4.But when a user changes his mind like in second table, if the user changes the input from 80 to 85, the value of ave becomes blank.Why is that?

Comment: so can users edit the content of the tables? And it's easier to see HTML when they aren't processed yet. Just right click, `View page source` and copy your html output. Better yet, put it into a snippet along with your javascript so we can run it.

Comment: @A.Lau -Sir in my view, it is a .blade.php file and some data of my table is coming from the database.I cant simply put in a snippet.In this blade file only the Term4 is editable or can place our input.If Term4 has data from the DB,the view just display.But if it has no data,thats the time i input a value but the problem is once i place a value and suddenly delete , use backspace or left the key up, the Ave column will be left blank and obviously something wrong with the js.What i do is just to refresh the page to input the fields again.This table here is likely the same with my backend DB.

Comment: I'm guessing that `ave` when it console logs is outputting correct information?

Comment: @A.Lau - log result :62.25
 50.4
 82.4
 63.25
 51.2
 83.2
(9times) NaN     - This NAN is the result of inputs the second time i tried to change the value of Term4

Comment: what do you get when you console log `parseInt(dInput);`

Comment: @A.Lau  var t = parseInt(dInput);    Result is NAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid that NaN issue, I made sure that changed input is taken as 0. And then recalculated average, then it works.

```
            $("tbody tr").each(function() {
            var total = 0;
            var ave = 0;
            var count = 1;


                $(this).children('td').not(':first').not(':last').each(function () {
                //"this" is the current element in the loop

                var number = ($(this).children('input').length == 0) ? $(this).html() : $(this).children('input').first().val();

                total += parseInt(number);
                ave = total/count;
                count++;
                });


              $(this).children('td').last().html(ave);


              if('.form-control'){
                $(this).on('keyup', 'td:eq( 4 ) input', function(){
                     $('.form-control').on("input", function() {
                        var dInput = parseInt(this.value);
                        if(!dInput || dInput === NaN) {
                            dInput = 0;
                        }

                    var total = 0;

                    var count = 1;
                    $(this).parent().siblings().not(':first').not(':last').each(function () { 

                    //"this" is the current element in the loop
                    var number = $(this).html();
                    total += parseInt(number);
                    count++;

                    });

                    total += dInput;
                    console.log(total);
                    console.log(count);
                    var ave = total/count; 

                    //console.log(ave);
                    $(this).parent().siblings(":last").html(ave);

                    calcTotalave();
                     });

             });
            } 

    });
    calcTotalave();
    // calculate total average
    function calcTotalave() {
        var totalAve = 0;
        $( ".aver" ).each(function() {
            console.log($(this).html());
            var thisAve = parseFloat($(this).html());
            if(!thisAve || thisAve === NaN) {
                thisAve = 0;
            }                

            totalAve += thisAve;

        });
        console.log(totalAve);
        $("#total-ave").val(totalAve);
    }
```

Comment: The computation is wrong, maybe the input and count is wrong.I'm figuring it out now.

Comment: i get proper average.

Comment: Sorry Sir, this code is correct.Its just because of mismatch of close brackets that i have.Finally your the one who got it right.I wish to up vote this answer but with my status its not allowed.Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: at T.Shah - Sir I forgot this last td outside the @endforeach which holds the total average of column Ave.Can you possibly add up or insert the logic inside the javascript?Here is the missing html: <tr>
                                    <th colspan="11">Total Average Grade :</th>
                                    <td>{!! Form::text('scholar_GPA',$card->scholar_GPA,['class'=>'form-control','name' => 'total-ave','id' => 'total-ave','value' => ''])  !!}</td>
                                </tr>

Comment: Updated to calculate total average. Your average column has class 'aver'. I used that to calculate total average. <td colspan="2" class="aver"> total</td> Remove name and id from this column. See to it that you don't assign this class to any other column - not even total average.  Now please accept this as answer...

Comment: Sir until now i did not come up with a solution.Im having a hard time looping in the html using jquery.